# get garmin gps coordinates into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jython, openlayers, garmin, gpsd

I would like to remove a marker and create a new marker in openlayers (javascript).  I can do this, but the trick is that I want to place the new marker at the current lat/lon position reported by my garmin etrex gps receiver.  I can get the new position from the receiver using gpsbabel and I can do this in python using subprocess.  The only way I can think to get this data into a javascript variable is using string substitution in a python CGI script.  The problem is the only way to get fresh data from the gps receiver is to refresh the page, which causes the map to go away for a short time, the current zoom level to be lost, and it just isn't a very clean way of doing this.  I'm looking for any ideas of how I can get coordinates from the gps into a javascript variable.

Would jython work, for getting the coordinates from python script into javascript?  I'm not familiar with it, but the reading I did today seemed to suggest this would require operating on port 8080, which is not ideal since I would like to use a python cgi script.  Maybe this is still possible.

I've looked for api's, but garmin's offerings seemed to be tied to their website and they are quite overkill if you just want the current coordinates.

I looked at gpsd, but had trouble with basic communication and further was unable to find anyway to communicate with the daemon through tcp port 2947 from javascript.

I am using gentoo linux.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2):

set a timer in client(using setTimeout javascript function) to update the marker location every 10 seconds or so.
for this you should use ajax to get last location from a server(which running the python code or something like that).

Comment: thank you for your answer.  I stumbled upon an explaination of how ajax works last night.  Your seconding this idea is enough motivation for me to look into it.  Since last night I have been trying to familiarize myself with how to create a plugin.  I guess both methods would work.

Answer (score 0):

So, as @sahmad suggested, it looks like AJAX is the way to go.  Like I said earlier, I started out trying to solve the problem with a browser plugin.   I used firebreath for this.  A couple of hard lessons learned along the way.  Most important, you either need to crash your plugin and reload the page or restart your browser when you make changes to your plugin.  I wasted many hours ignorant to this simple fact.  This plugin direction also took longer for me because my C++ skills are in the early stages of development.

The AJAX route was quite simple to learn. I used this page as my starting point: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php

I thought I would complete my example and report back my solution then this matter would be all finished.  However, in the process of creating my example, I came up with another question. Here are files:

I modified the html file like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Ajax Example</title>
<script language="Javascript">
function xmlhttpPost(strURL) {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    // Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
        }
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring());
}

function getquerystring() {
    qstr = 'latLon=' + escape(document.forms['f1'].lat.value + ':' + document.forms['f1'].lon.value);
    return qstr;
}

function updatepage(str){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
}

function moveMarker(){
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML= parseFloat(document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML) + 1
    xmlhttpPost("/cgi-bin/ajax3.py")

    var latFromGPS = document.forms["f1"]["gpsLat"].value;
    var lonFromGPS = document.forms["f1"]["gpsLon"].value;

    document.forms["f1"]["lat"].value=latFromGPS;
    document.forms["f1"]["lon"].value=lonFromGPS;

}    
window.setInterval('moveMarker()', 2000);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="f1">
    <p id=timer>0</p>
    <p><input type="text" id="lat" name="lat" value="35.0"> </p>
    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="gpsLat" value="35.0"> -->
    <p><input type="text" id="lon" name="lon" value="-106.0"> </p>
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my python cgi script (for this example it should be saved as ajax3.py in cgi-bin):

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import cgi

import cgitb; cgitb.enable() # for troubleshooting

print "Content-type: text/html"
print ""

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

gpsLat = float(form.getvalue("latLon").split(":")[0])
gpsLon = float(form.getvalue("latLon").split(":")[1])

print '<input type="hidden" name="gpsLat" value="%s">' % (gpsLat + 0.001)
print '<input type="hidden" name="gpsLon" value="%s">' % (gpsLon + 0.001)
```

I tried to simulate the GPS reporting coordinates by simply adding one-thousandth of a degree to both the latitude & longitude in the cgi script.  Then sending this result back to the original page via hidden input types.  What was interesting, was that I essentially have to call moveMarker() at twice the frequency that I want coordinates reported back.  This isn't a problem, but I would like to understand why this is.  From my naive standpoint, I figured that the

```
xmlhttpPost("/cgi-bin/ajax3.py")
```

command would execute and complete before then next command

```
var latFromGPS = document.forms["f1"]["gpsLat"].value;
```

was executed.  This is not, however, the case.  So does the first command complete only after a certain amount of time or does it not complete until after moveMarker() completes?